# If I need to install the latest Java SDK, what apt-get should I install?

Tags: java, linux, unix, aptitude

I'm on Ubuntu Maverick.

There are too many packages when I run `apt-cache search java`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this to install mine: http://happy-coding.com/install-sun-java6-jdk-on-ubuntu-10-04-lucid/

Answer (score 3):

This should be on askubuntu.com, but to save you some time:

`sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk`

I think that's right. It'll install the extra packages you need, iirc.

Answer (score 0):

I always download the bin from the sun/oracle site and run it. I then use update-alternatives a few times and that is all it takes.